# Jquery Validate Not Showing Error Messages

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I started using the jquery plugin for validation and am puzzled why it's not working, here is my javascript code for it:
"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shipper_form').validate({
        errorLabelContainer: "#errors",
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            business: "required",
            address: {
                required: true,
            },
            zipcode: {
                required: true,
            },
            phone: {
                required: true,
            },
            contact_name: {
                required: true,
            },
        },
        messages : {
            email : "Required Email *",
            business : "Required Business *",
            address : "Required Address *",
            zipcode : "Required Zip Code*",
            phone : "Required Phone*",
            contact_name : "Required Contact Name*",
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
</script>"
```

Form:

```
<div id="errors"></div>
      <form method="post" action="signup.php">
        <table cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" style="width: 300px;" class="form-control placeholder" placeholder="Email Address">
                    <span id="email_success" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" style="color: green; display: none;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    <input type="text" id="business" name="business" style="width: 300px;" class="form-control placeholder" placeholder="Business Name or DBA">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" style="color: green; display: none;"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
     </form>
```

The error messages shows up for email, but not for business or any of the other ones, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `#shipper_form` element? No element has that ID name...

Comment: Sorry about that,  I left out the id to the form , which is "id=shipper_form", when I moved it over.

Comment: Please post your solution below as an answer.

Comment: Just noticed this, the jquery-validate was conflicting with another javascript file in my case, so I removed the other file when I need to use the validation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the validation was not working because both jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js was added to the page. In that case validation was working in half of the pages and was not working in the other half.( By not working I mean; the form still gets validated correctly but no error message was shown.  )

Removing the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js from the page fixed the problem.